# flashgot icon not appears on firefox bar?

Tags: wget

I reset my firefox settings. Before reseting firefox, there was an icon appeared on firefox (beside address bar) of flashgot when watching flash videos. Now it is not showing there..after reseting the firefox. I reconfigured every add-ons and all. But it is not showing up??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now i use Download helper for selecting flashgot. DH has a menu which leads to flashgot. It much better than before.

Answer (score 0):

go to View/Toolbars/Customize and drag the Flashgot icons.

Also, in FlashGot options/FlashGot Media check 'Show toolbar button'

[image]